# C string is not running

Tags: c, scanf

As I am a novice Programmer and Coder So, I have taken 30 days of coding challenge in `Hackerrank`, but when I a running simple string storing problem in  C, It shows no of errors 
The Code is

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int i = 4;
    double d = 4.0;
    char s[] = "HackerRank ";
    // Declare second integer, double, and String variables.

    // Read and save an integer, double, and String to your variables.

    // Print the sum of both integer variables on a new line.

    // Print the sum of the double variables on a new line.

    // Concatenate and print the String variables on a new line
    // The 's' variable above should be printed first.
int ie;double de;char re[1000];
printf("Enter the int,double,string value :");
scanf("%d %lf %s",&ie,&de,re);
printf("\n%d\n%lf\n%s",(ie+i),(de+d),s);
printf("%s\n",re);
 return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
12 
4.0
is the best place to learn
```

Expected output:

```
16
8.0
HackerRank is the best place to learn
```

Actual output:

```
Enter the int,double,string value :
16
8.000000
HackerRank is
```

Comment: If you run it yourself, with the specified input, what is the output? Is it the same as the expected output? Is it *exactly* the same as the expected output, including spaces and newlines?

Comment: Your problem can be solved by reading the documentation for `scanf` and what `%s` does.

Comment: Also, `printf` `%lf` either has undefined behavior (in C89) or is equivalent to `%f` (in C99+), so there's really no reason to use it.

Comment: The `%s` conversion specification skips leading white space, accumulates non-white-space characters, and stops at the next white space.  The `is` contains two non-white-space characters; the rest is ignored.  Maybe you need `%[^\n]` as the conversion specification.  You should also protect against overflow (`%999[^\n]` — though that's not crucial this time, it is a good habit to get into).  You should test the return value from `scanf()` to see whether you got 3 values or not.

Answer (score 1):

The points are:

- You shouldn't print what are not expected like `Enter the int,double,string value :`, or the judge system will treat them as garbage and treat as Wrong Answer.
- `%s` will stop reading at whitespace. `fgets` can be used to read one line. `%d` and `%lf` won't consume newline characters, so some care is needed.
- Difference in printing format of floating point number may or may not be accepted, depending on problem setting. This isn't fixed in the example below.

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> /* for using strchr() */
int main() {
    int i = 4;
    double d = 4.0;
    char s[] = "HackerRank ";

    int ie;double de;char re[1000];
    char *lf;
    fgets(re, sizeof(re), stdin); sscanf(re, "%d", &ie);
    fgets(re, sizeof(re), stdin); sscanf(re, "%lf", &de);
    fgets(re, sizeof(re), stdin);
    if ((lf = strchr(re, '\n')) != NULL) *lf = '\0'; /* remove newline character if it exists */
    printf("%d\n%f\n%s",(ie+i),(de+d),s);
    printf("%s\n",re);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i = 4;
    double d = 4.0;
    char s[] = "HackerRank ";
    int x;
    double y;
    char z[50];
    scanf(" %d %lf\n%[^\n]", &x, &y, z);
    printf("%d\n", x+i);
    printf("%.1lf\n", y+d);
    printf("%s", s);
    printf("%s", z);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: do not- printf("Enter the int,double,string value :"); as it will be printed to stdout and that's wrong output as output is already specified. You cannot print anything other than the results after the operation.

Comment: also print "Hackerrank " stored in s[] before you print re[]